# Avoid type cast with type member and sub-typing

Tags: scala, casting, path-dependent-type, subtyping

I am having trouble with path dependent types and pattern matching:

```
trait View[A]

trait Foo {
  type Bar

  def defaultBar: Bar
}
trait Baz extends Foo {
  def view(init: Bar): View[Bar]
}

trait Test {
  val foo: Foo

  def bar: foo.Bar = foo.defaultBar

  def test(): Option[View[foo.Bar]] =
    foo match {
      case b: Baz => Some(b.view(bar))
      case _ => None
    }
}
```

This fails because scalac doesn't identify `foo` with `b`. As a result, it only works with two casts:

```
      case b: Baz => Some(b.view(bar.asInstanceOf[b.Bar]).asInstanceOf[View[foo.Bar]])
```

Surely there must be a clean way to avoid the casts?

Comment: i'm not sure, but aren't such type casts against the logic of path-dependant types? Then why not to use type projection with covariance?

Comment: I cannot use projections because the basic member type is too general. That would only work if I go through the hoop of `trait Foo[F <: Foo[F]] { type Bar; def defaultBar: F#Bar }` which I really would like to avoid.

Comment: Are you missing some code from `Baz`? In this sample above you never define `Baz` as a type for `Bar`.  Your test is matching on a `Foo` but your code never makes `Baz` a valid `Foo`.

Comment: @iain `Baz` is sub-type of `Foo`. If I match `foo` and find it is an instance of `Baz`, obviously `b eq foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do without using projections and restricting the type as `defaultBar` we can override it to unrelated data types

for eg

`trait MyFoo extends Foo {
  override def defaultBar: Int
}`